# In my.cnf file, changed bind-address to 127.0.0.1 and it still allows remote connections

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, database-administration

My root user can be accessed remotely, and my goal is to **only allow it from localhost**.

First I tried changing it's permissions to 'root'@'localhost'.

Then I checked /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which includes some other .cnf files. I changed them all to:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

I restarted MySQL and Apache, and I still can access it remotely.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'bind_address'` show?

Comment: why muck with bind_address, why not just remove `root@%` and `root@whatever` mysql users, and leave the only "root" user as `root@localhost`, so no TCP/IP connections as root will be allowed.  Why restart apache? What the plastic does that have to do with which connections MySQL accepts? The information provided question is too vaguely imprecise to allow specific guidance.

Comment: @user3783243 it shows: Variable_name=Value; bind_address=0.0.0.0

Comment: @spencer7593 did you read my post? That was the first thing I tried

Comment: That's your issue the `bind-address` didn't take affect and it is still global.

Comment: Maybe https://serverfault.com/questions/782118/mysql-5-7-bind-address-doesnt-work is related which mysql are you using?

Comment: @user3783243 I'm using 5.7. Thank you for your help, I'll try that solution.

Comment: I read your post, but its not at all clear what it is you tried.  What the plastic is this supposed to mean? "changing its permissions to 'root'@'localhost'"  Doesn't sound like any rows were removed from mysql.users and a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement was issued, and doesn't sound like any DROP USER statements were issued, and we don't even see any evidence that a `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root'` was executed.

Comment: @spencer7593 I did those things you mentioned. My intention was to be clear and objective, perhaps my knowledge is not at the level you would like. Since we're giving feedback, you should cut the "what the plastic" stuff.

Comment: It''s not a "level of knowledge" issue. It's about describing the actions that were taken in vague imprecise language. "tried changing permissions" ... how exactly? by issuing a CHANGE PERMISSIONS sql statement and restarting apache?